# int not returning same value from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, int

I have saved value in Singletone as NSString. When I want to convert to int, value is some random number. For example, I am calling `NSString *numberCoupons = [Manager sharedInstance].userProfile.numberOfCoupons`, po numberCoupons returning normal value: **40**. 
 
But problem is in next line, when I want to convert string to value: `int coupons = (int)numberCoupons`; It is returning some random number, etc. **421414**. 
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `int coupons = [numberCoupons integerValue];`

Comment: Yes, this is working. What is main difference between these two converters?

Comment: `(int)numberCoupons` is used for type casting.

Answer (score 1):

`numerofCoupons` is obviously an `NSNumber` object which is used to store numbers within Objective-C collection classes (`NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, etc) as only objects can be stored in them.

To get the wrapped value out of the object use:

```
 NSInteger coupons = [numberOfCoupons integerValue]
```

I would recommend redeclaring `numberOfCoupons` as `NSInteger`, and not `NSNumber`, as `NSNumber` objects are difficult and expensive to manipulate compared to the primitive types they wrap.

If the value needs to go into a collection class then wrap it in an `NSNumber` object when adding it and unwrap it when removing it.

Comment: NSNumber wrapping is actually not too expansive, most of the time you won't notice. And as you mention, they easily go into collections. The big advantage is that they can actually be nil, although that might also come as a disadvantage depending on the design and context. :)

Comment: @Eiko Well I have to disagree.  Even adding `1` to the value wrapped in an `NSNumber` object means sending a couple of messages and allocating a new object.  If you do this alot, you will probably notice.

Comment: New instances are not created necessarily. NSNumber shares/reuses/caches instances, which is easy as it's immutable. Of course I wouldn't use it for number crunching, but there's no reason to deny their benefits, and the given question with userProfile.numberOfCoupons looks like a typical storage application - and this absolutely doesn't look like number crunching.  And the data might already be wrapped. Don't get lost in micro optimizations if it doesn't really matter (which will easily show up in intruments).

Comment: Well I don't see their benefits at all here; there can only ever be `0 to lots` of coupons so there is no need for `nil`, which appears to be its only benefit over `NSUInteger`, until it needs storing within a collection class.  Therefore this is not an optimization but a natural way most programmers would choose to represent the number of coupons.

Comment: I thought so, too. Until I thought - well, maybe it's a server based application, and the number of coupons is still unknown.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `(int)numberOfCoupons` you are asking that the *value* in the variable `numberOfCoupons` be *cast* to the type `int`.

Now the value in a variable of type `NSString *` is a reference to an object, that is a memory address. When (Objective-)C casts a reference to an integer type you get back the memory address. This is the “random” value you are seeing.

What you need to do is send a message to the *object referenced by the value* in your variable requesting that it return an integer value equivalent to itself. `NSString` has a method `intValue` for this, so `[numberOfCoupons intValue]` will do what you wish.

There is a whole family of `xValue` methods to obtain various integer and floating-point values of different precision/size.

Note: if you have a reference to an `NSNumber`, rather than an `NSString`, then exactly the same code will work.

Note 2: if you do have an `NSNumber` then the cast expression you first tried may return a value which has a completely different magnitude than you might expect for a memory address. This is because some integer values are represented by special *tagged addresses* which don't actually reference a real object. This is an optimisation you normally would not notice, except when you accidentally cast the reference value to an integer...

HTH